# Why does ubuntu 12.04 LTS provide samba4 alpha?

Tags: 12.04, samba, lts

I was surprised to see an alpha package in an LTS release. Why put such an alpha package in an LTS release, no matter how stable it can be?  It can be misleading for careless people who didn' t check the version number in detail.

Comment: alpha does not necessarily imply instability. LTS also does not imply stability, at least not necessarily on the first day of the release. LTS becomes more stable over time as bugs are fixed and as it is supported for longer.

Comment: I know that in the linux world. But I wouldn' t put it in an LTS release.

Comment: Well, LTS refers to the lengh of support , not "stability". Obviously it will be more stable over time as bugs are fixed, but not necessarily stable on day 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Samba package (even in Ubuntu 13.04) points at Samba version 3 (specifically 3.6 in 12.04), so a user looking to install Samba would install version 3 of the software (as well as would any software that depended on Samba).

The samba4 package has been available in Ubuntu since at least as far back as 10.04 (older versions are no longer supported, so a package search doesn't show results from them). For various good reasons packages aren't removed from the repositories (there are cases where this happens, usually when the package ceases to exist), and surely wouldn't be removed for an LTS release only to be readded later.

Further, to install Samba version 4, a user would have to specifically look for and install the samba4 package.

Lastly, samba4 (even in 13.04) is in the Universe repository, and as such is not supported at all by Canonical. So from a business standpoint, Samba 4 being available in 12.04 is irrelevant.

From https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

> Universe - Community maintained software, i.e. not officially
>   supported software.